# Command line tool for easy multiline regex search and replace

Tags: command-line, regular-expression, software-rec

I use PCRE regular expressions for search and replace very often when working with a text editor and I was left quite unhappy after I found out that in powerful Unix command line tools like `perl`, `awk` or `sed` it's fairly complicated to use a bit advanced multiline regex and requires various hard to remember syntax for various situations.

Is there a command line tool for Linux in which search and replace (for all occurences in the whole file) using a more complex multiline regex is as simple as:

```
magicregextool 's/.* > (.*) joined the channel\.\n(((?!.* \1 (was kicked from channel\.|was banned from channel\.)\n).*\n)+?.*\1 disconnected)/\2/' file.txt
```

i.e. the regex to match is the same as I would place in the `search for` field in a text editor, the replacement string can handle multiline regex as well and there's no need for any convoluted syntax?

**EDIT:**

Per request I'm attaching an input which I'd use the example regex above for and explaining what I want it to actually do.

An input like this:

```
2016-05-16 06:17:00 > foobar joined the channel.
2016-05-16 06:17:13 <foobar> hi
2016-05-16 06:18:30 > foobar was kicked from channel.
2016-05-16 06:18:30 > foobar disconnected
2016-05-16 06:20:13 > user joined the channel.
2016-05-16 06:20:38 <user> bye
2016-05-16 06:21:57 > user disconnected
```

should produce this output:

```
2016-05-16 06:17:00 > foobar joined the channel.
2016-05-16 06:17:13 <foobar> hi
2016-05-16 06:18:30 > foobar was kicked from channel.
2016-05-16 06:18:30 > foobar disconnected
2016-05-16 06:20:38 <user> bye
2016-05-16 06:21:57 > user disconnected
```

The regex matches any line that contains `[username] joined the channel` and looks for a line below it that contains `[username] disconnected` **unless** there is a `[username] was kicked from channel.` or `[username] was banned from channel.` between those 2 lines.

The replacement string then replaces the matched pattern with every line following the line with `[username] joined the channel` effectively deleting the line `2016-05-16 06:20:13 > user joined the channel.` from the input above.

Most likely doesn't make any sense to you but **this is just an example regex similar to one I've dealt with recently. Please keep in mind I'm NOT looking for a solution for this particular problem or similar problems with the Unix tools I listed above. I'm looking for a command line tool which can use unmodified "search for" and replacement strings that I use in a text editor (Geany, in particular but that shouldn't really matter) without complicated syntax or requiring some added programming logic to deal with the multiline "search for" and replacement strings.**

Comment: Uh.. that's exactly what `sed` does.  `sed --in-place 's/expr/replacement/' /path/to/file`

Comment: @DopeGhoti Are you certain you read my question properly? I'm pretty sure `sed` doesn't support multiline regex with such simple syntax and as far as I know it doesn't support lookahead or lookbehind at all.

Comment: There's a snippet to load the whole file into sed's pattern space: `sed -e :a -e '$!{N;b a}' -e other_commands...` . This way you can use multiline regex

Comment: `ssed` (super sed) supports perl regex

Comment: @basin It's less of a problem of availability of perl regex and more of a problem with "search and replace" using a more complex regex that's supposed to match (and replace with) multiline strings. As I stated in my question `perl` itself cannot do this without some added programming logic dealing with the multiline regex which makes the syntax more complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why Perl isn't acceptable here.  On the inputs you provided, this line gives the output you asked for:

```
perl -0777p -e 's/.* > (.*) joined the channel\.\n(((?!.* \1 (was kicked from channel\.|was banned from channel\.)\n).*\n)+?.*\1 disconnected)/\2/mg' irc.txt
```

The `-e` argument is exactly the first argument to your `magicregextool` except that I added the `/mg` regex modifier.  This may not be "unmodified" but it doesn't seem unreasonable either.  If you don't want to type in the whole line, how about this script as `magicregextool`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -0777p
BEGIN { $::arg = shift @ARGV; }
eval $arg;
```

Or even:

```
#!/bin/sh
perl -0777pe $*
```

Then you just type:

```
magicregextool 's/.* > (.*) joined the channel\.\n(((?!.* \1 (was kicked from channel\.|was banned from channel\.)\n).*\n)+?.*\1 disconnected)/\2/mg' irc.txt
```

Which is the same as your sample (again other than adding the `/mg` modifier).

An additional benefit to this is that if you are running multiple related search/replace operations on each file, you can put them together in the same script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -0777p
s/.* > (.*) joined the channel\.\n(((?!.* \1 (was kicked from channel\.|was banned from channel\.)\n).*\n)+?.*\1 disconnected)/\2/mg;
s/(some other\n)matched text/\1/mg;
```